# Editing Bash Script To Display Output

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a script that cycles through several servers and if a particular user is found it will output their name. I'd like to modify the individual statements so that if a user isn't found '`NO USER IDENTIFIED`' is output.

Here is an individual code snippet:

```
echo "environment1" sshpass -p $ldappw ssh $ldapuser@12.34.567.65 'mysql -h website.com -u topuser -ppassword dbname-e "select concat(FIRST,LAST) from users;"' | grep -i ${username}
```

I would appreciate the assistance of the community in modifying the statement to give me the desired output.

Comment: `grep` returns failure if no lines are output. You can use that with `if ! grep ....; then echo 'NO USER IDENTIFIED'; fi`.

Comment: simply write `... | (grep -i ${username} || echo "NO USER IDENTIFIED")`

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to just write this:

```
echo "environment1" sshpass -p $ldappw ssh $ldapuser@12.34.567.65 'mysql -h website.com -u topuser -ppassword dbname-e "select concat(FIRST,LAST) from users;"' | (grep -i ${username} || echo "NO USER IDENTIFIED")
```

**Explanation**

As Etan points it out, grep returns failure if no lines are selected. This is what the [grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) says on that:

> The  exit  status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not
>   found. If an error occurred the exit status is 2.

Bash evaluates the right side of `||` only if the left side was false. As the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) says:

> The && and || operators do not evaluate expression2 if the value of
>   expression1 is sufficient to determine the return value of the entire
>   conditional expression.

So if grep cannot select a row which matches `${username}`, `echo` will do the job.

**Notes**

- Consider selecting only the desired user `select concat(FIRST,LAST) from users where concat(FIRST,LAST) like '%${username}%;'`. With this trick you can do an exact match before grep (just remove `%` characters from the like).
- Consider using the `-N` (Do not write column names in results.) and the `-s` (Silent mode.) parameters of mysql, so it produces less output.